# Subquery returned more than 1 value in sqlc#

Tags: sql

SQL Command string to run in ADO.Net. the problem it's probably returned more than 1 rows inside the subquery.

```
string str = "
select 
 (select (quantity) from Orderinfo where iron=1 and rno=o.rno) as iron
 ,(select (quantity) from Orderinfo where wash=1 and rno=o.rno) as wash 
 ,(select (quantity) from Orderinfo where dryclean=1 and rno=o.rno) as dryclean 
 ,o.rno
 ,o.id
 ,o.name
 ,(select sum(convert(int,d.quantity)) from orderinfo as d where d.rno=o.rno) as quantity
 ,o.status 
from orderinfo as o 
where o.status='Order in Process' 
group by o.rno,o.id ,o.status ,o.name";
```

Comment: Use select top 1....... instead.

Comment: Please treat your SQL queries with care, they should be as readable, as maintainable and as clear as your application code is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your desired result correctly, you need to get the sum of the quantities:

```
string str = "
select 
 (select sum(quantity) from Orderinfo where iron=1 and rno=o.rno) as iron
 ,(select sum(quantity) from Orderinfo where wash=1 and rno=o.rno) as wash 
 ,(select sum(quantity) from Orderinfo where dryclean=1 and rno=o.rno) as dryclean 
 ,o.rno
 ,o.id
 ,o.name
 ,(select sum(convert(int,d.quantity)) from orderinfo as d where d.rno=o.rno) as quantity
 ,o.status 
from orderinfo as o 
where o.status='Order in Process' 
group by o.rno,o.id ,o.status ,o.name";
```

BTW I'm assuming it's correct you want the quantity of the entire "o.rno" independent of the specific "o.id". Otherwise the sub queries are not needed.